# Why is it illegal to use "la" with a register indirect operand in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I got a homework assignment back graded to 8/10 points because I "illegally" used load address to set the destination register to the s register contents.  Shown below is operation in question:

```
la  $t1, ($t0)
```

$t0 was holding a hexidecimal word which we were to convert into decimal, but that's not important.  MARS (the MIPS simulator we use for assembly language class) suggests this when you type la:

"la $t1, ($t2)    Load Address: Set $t1 to contents of $t2"

She just got done telling the entire class (who all did the same thing) that it was illegal, and then I showed her how MARS suggested that instruction.  Program runs fine, and is included here:

So, my long-winded question: is that really illegal, or does she just not know what she's talking about?

```
# Project/Class Description:
# Formats an IP address from a value in memory 
# using shifts and AND operations.
#
.data
inHex:  .asciiz "IP Address in Hex: "
header: .asciiz "\nFormatted IP Address: "

IPinHex: .word 0x58dc45c3
dot:    .asciiz "."

.text globl

main:
li  $v0, 4      # print hex header
la  $a0, inHex
syscall

la  $t0, IPinHex
li  $v0, 34     # print hex number
lw  $a0, ($t0)
syscall

li  $v0, 4      # print int header
la  $a0, header
syscall

la  $t0, IPinHex    
lw  $t0, ($t0)  # IP address in hex

li  $t5, 0xff000000 # AND value
li  $t6, 24     # shiftAmt
li  $t7, 3      # loop count

loop:               
addi    $t7, $t7, -1    # count--
la  $t1, ($t0)  
and $t1, $t1, $t5   # isolate chunk of hex number
srlv    $t1, $t1, $t6   # shift down to the right

li  $v0, 1      # print int
la  $a0, ($t1)
syscall

li  $v0, 4      # print a "."
la  $a0, dot
syscall

srl $t5, $t5, 8 # shift AND value for next iteration
addi    $t6, $t6, -8    # shiftAmt-= 8

bnez    $t7, loop   # while (loop!=0)


la  $t1, ($t0)  # print last int
and $t1, $t1, $t5   # isolate chunk of hex number

li  $v0, 1      # print int
la  $a0, ($t1)
syscall         

exit:               # exit()
li  $v0, 10     
syscall
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`la` is a pseudoinstruction. That form might not be illegal in your assembler, but it certainly makes no sense.  `la` does not access memory, it just loads the address of the second operand.

The gnu assembler (`gas`) chokes on your instruction saying `Error:Expression too complex`.

If `($t0)` is allowed (e.g. in MARS, and clang's built-in assembler), the address of `($t0)` is of course `$t0` so what you have there is just a register-to-register copy for which you should use `move` (which is yet another pseudoinstruction that usually gets translated to `addu $dst, $src, $0`).

The `move $dst, $src` pseudo-instruction works in all MIPS assemblers, and has the right semantic meaning for human readers.

Only use `la` for its intended purpose of getting a symbol address into a register,
`la $t0, my_static_data`.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why MARS would even allow me to do that then.  Thanks for the very thorough answer, I get it now!